# Deleting charts in excel using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

How to delete all charts in Excel Workbooks using VBA.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveChart.Parent.Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of your needs. It prompts the user also, via MsgBox as a precaution against deleting wanted charts/objects.

```
Sub delAllChartsInWorkbook()
'
' delchart Macro
' Macro recorded 1/4/2016 by ejbytes
'
    'Variables
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim LIST As Integer
    Dim currSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
    Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String
    Dim tmpName As String


    'Define Variables
    count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

    '****************************************************
    'Loop example using a count.                        *
    '****************************************************
    For LIST = 1 To count
        MsgBox "This is a loop example. This is Sheet: " _
                 & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(LIST).Name
    Next LIST



    '****************************************************
    '* Loop example all sheet in this workbook          *
    '* Cycle through each Sheet                         *
    '* Nested Loops:                                    *
    '*                                                  *
    '* Outer Loop                                       *
    '****************************************************
    For Each currSheet In Worksheets
        MsgBox "Current sheet: " & currSheet.Name

        '****************************************************
        '* Cycle through each Chart Object on current sheet *
        '* Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects                    *
        '*                                                  *
        '* Inner Loop                                       *
        '****************************************************
        For Each myChart In currSheet.ChartObjects

            QuestionToMessageBox = "DELETE chart: '" & myChart.Name & "' ?"
            YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = _
                MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "Yes/No Comment?")

            If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbNo Then
                MsgBox "Chart: " & myChart.Name & " skipped."
            Else
                tmpName = myChart.Name
                myChart.Delete
                MsgBox "Chart: " & tmpName & " Deleted!"
                'Modify my chart? You can do this too:
                'myChart.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
            End If
        Next myChart
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete all charts on the active sheet:

```
Sub DeleteChartsOnActiveSheet()
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
End Sub
```

To delete all charts on all sheets in the active workbook:

```
Sub DeleteChartsInActiveWorkbook()
  ' delete chart sheets
  ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Delete

  ' delete charts embedded in other sheets
  Dim sh As Object
  For Each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    sh.ChartObjects.Delete
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```vb
Sub DeleteChartsInThisWorkbook()

Dim Msg As String  
Dim cws As Chart  
Dim cobj As ChartObject  
Dim wb As Workbook  
Dim ws As Worksheet

1    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler  
'    Delete chart sheets  
2    Set wb = ThisWorkbook  
3    For Each cws In wb.Charts  
4      Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
5      cws.Delete  
6      Application.DisplayAlerts = True  
7    Next cws  

'    Delete charts embedded in all other worksheets  
8    For Each ws In wb.Sheets  
9      For Each cobj In ws.ChartObjects  
10       cobj.Delete  
11     Next cobj  
12   Next ws  

13   Exit Sub  
ErrorHandler:  
14   If Err.Number <> 0 Then  
15      Msg = "Error # " & str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & chr(13) _  
            & "Sub DeleteChartsInThisWorkbook() on Sheet#(Name)" & chr(13) _  
            & "Error Line: " & Erl & chr(13) _  
            & Err.Description  
16       MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext  
17   End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Plagiarized solution.

Comment: Can you please provide attribution instead of saying in a comment that your work is plagiarized? Edit the credit to the author into the answer, please.